# Firefox doesn't update?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, updates

I am using firefox 35.0.1 and tried to update to 36.0 today morning, I opened the "About Firefox" dialogue box to update firefox, it shows "Checking for Update" and shows that [image: Restart Firefox To Update] even without giving the consent to download the update, it even didn't download any data.

When I click "Restart Firefox To Update", it simply doesn't restart, so I manually restarted ff, but nothing has changed.

Why Firefox behaves like this and how can I resolve the problem?   (I would like to avoid a reinstallation)

Note:I am using Windows 7 64bit, anyone can find more data at [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1048556), click "More System Details" on the right side of the page.
[image: Updated Screenshot]

Comment: Home or Corporate network?  If you don't delete the profile all the reinstallation will do is replace your Firefox data not your user profile.

Comment: @Ramhound Home use.

Comment: Is the service that handles this feature running?

Comment: @Ramhound Don't know, I have just attached a screenshot of the Update option window.

Comment: Update worked fine here. Also Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Even i have windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

1) Uncheck "Use a background service to install updates". This is safer as long as you don't mind being bothered by the User Account Control dialog. At least you could stop the installation if necessary.

2) You selected "Automatically install updates" so of course it won't ask for your permission. If you want to know first, select "Check for updates, ...". If you proceed with the installation, it will still confirm add-ons in this mode.